# Laravel 5.0 Socialite with Wunderlist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, wunderlist

I've created a custom Provider for Laravel Socialite.
The authentication part is going well until i'll try to call the user method.

Not sure what's going wrong.
[Method documentation at wunderlist](https://developer.wunderlist.com/documentation/endpoints/user)

My code:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function getUserByToken($token)
{
    $response = $this->getHttpClient()->get('https://a.wunderlist.com/api/v1/users', [
        'X-Access-Token: ' . $token . ' X-Client-ID: ' . $this->clientId
    ]);

    return json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentException in MessageFactory.php line 202:
allow_redirects must be true, false, or array
```

Do i miss things in the options array?

Jos

Answer (score 0):

Actually socialite is not supposed to do something like this. But instead you may use Guzzle. There is a good video at laracasts. Just search for `Easy HTTP Requests`. And here's the code that you may use for guzzle:

```
$client = new \Guzzle\Service\Client('a.wunderlist.com/api/v1/');
$response = $client->get('user')->send();
// If you want this response in array:
$user = $response->json();
```

Just [read the docs](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org) here.

Comment: Hi @Aditya Giri, 

Thank you. I must say Socialite uses Guzzle. I'll try to use it directly instead.

Thanks.

Comment: When using Guzzle directly i get the same error. I've added a stack dump:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10376551/stack.txt

Comment: Well even I tried to create a sample app with this api but I didn't get any errors like that.

Comment: I did some further tests as well and calling this part with a straight forward curl i get at least some json feedback. I keep you posted about my outcome..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77959/discussion-between-aditya-giri-and-jos-koomen).

Answer (score 0):

When using this with straight forward curl there is no issue.
As far as i can see the issue lies in the headers i'll parse.

The following solution is something i can live with, although it's not perfect.

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'X-Access-Token: ' . $token;
$headers[] = 'X-Client-ID: ' . $this->clientId;
$response = $this->getHttpClient()->get('a.wunderlist.com/api/v1/user', [
        'config' => [
            'curl' => [
                CURLOPT_POST => 0,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
            ]
        ]
    ]);
    return json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
```